# Best of both worlds: python packaging for a game

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe

I am currently trying to package a game made with python and pygame and I am running into some issues.

I am using `py2exe` to package and have looked up some question on here about it but I couldn't find a great solution. I want to end up with a folder, containing an `exe`, that I can compress and put online. Running the `setup.py` works fine except it puts all the dependencies into `library.zip`. This means that the program, when run, does not work.

I found that someone else was running into this issue and they ended using the `"skip archive = true"` option to solve it. And while, yes, that does work for me too I was hoping there was a method that would still let the program be run without trouble but wouldn't clutter the folder with countless files.

To be very precise the issue I'm running into with the `library.zip` is:

```
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading pygame\mixer.pyd
```

Which, if I understand it properly, means that the program can not reach/find the mixer module of Pygame.

Here is the setup script I am currently using (and that isn't working):

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

data_files = [('resources', ['resources/step.wav',
                    'resources/wind2.wav',
                    'resources/The Steppes.ogg',
                    'resources/warrior3-nosword-notassle.png',
                    'resources/warrior3-sword.png',
                    'resources/warrior2-blood1.png',
                    'resources/warrior2-blood2.png',
                    'resources/warrior2-blood3.png',
                    'resources/warrior2-blood4.png',
                    'resources/warrior3-up.png',
                    'resources/warrior3-kneel.png',
                    'resources/warrior3-kneel-nosword.png',
                    'resources/warrior2-blood2-kneel.png',
                    'resources/warrior2-blood3-kneel.png',
                    'resources/warrior2-blood4-kneel.png',
                    'resources/warrior3-death.png',
                    'resources/warrior3-offarm.png',
                    'resources/menu1.png',
                    'resources/plains3-top-nomount.png',
                    'resources/mountains.png',
                    'resources/plains5-bottom.png',
                    'resources/plains3-bottom.png',
                    'resources/cloud1.png',
                    'resources/warrior2-sword.png',
                    'resources/warrior2-hand.png',
                    'resources/blue-tassle1.png',
                    'resources/blue-tassle2.png',
                    'resources/blue-tassle3.png',
                    'resources/blue-tassle4.png'])]

setup(options = {'py2exe': {"bundle_files": 1}},
    data_files = data_files,
    console = [{'script': "steppes2.0.py"}],
    zipfile = None
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

This code in your setup.py should do the trick of producing a single executable (you will still have to distribute msvc dlls separately)

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
      options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
      console = [{'script': "myscript.py"}],
      zipfile = None,
)
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. Exactly the same issue as before. My problem is not getting it as one executable (though that would be nice) the problem is that it can't access stuff being packaged in with it. If I run the program through command prompt it runs fine but if I package and run the exe it gives me the error mentioned above. I'll post my current setup script, which might help.

Comment: Then maybe a problem with missing dlls, it seems that py2exe sometimes thinks a dll is part of the system while it should include it in the package, take a look here http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/OverridingCriteraForIncludingDlls. If you decompress the produced exe is there a libogg-0.dll file inside it?

Comment: I didn't actually check for the libogg-0.dll but the hack on that website didn't work, nor did I expect it to. As I've said the exe works perfectly if the files are including directly inside the folder (right next to the exe) but doesn't work if they included in as the library.zip or as packaged into the exe. So the problem isn't stuff missing but the exe being unable to properly access it.